# Make a div slide up, wait 5 seconds and go down with CSS Animation

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations

The objective is to make a `div` slide up, wait 5 seconds and go down.

Here is fiddle with what I have done so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/j95aeduL/32/

Comment: add a delay  https://jsfiddle.net/j95aeduL/42/ ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with jQuery.

using the method `.slideUp()` you'll be able to collapse the div containing the content in a sliding up motion. Then using `.delay()` you can set a delay of 5 seconds. In order to display the content again, call `.slideDown()`.
When you chain these animations, the code to make this work looks like the following: `$('.content').slideUp(500).delay(5000).slideDown(500);`

Gotcha to point out is that when using this code, it's best to disable the button from being clicked again when the animations or delay are in progress. Else another sequence will be triggered once the first one is completed.

Here's a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.content').slideUp(500).delay(5000).slideDown(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #19c63c;
  border: 1px solid #169630;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Start</button>
<div class="content">content to display...</div>
```

In case you don't want to use jQuery's animations you can create your own by just using CSS. In this case, you create a `.hide` class. When it's added to a div it will trigger the slide up animation. After 5 seconds you remove it again. The CSS for animating the transition is `transition: all .3s ease-out;`

The code for this is as per below.

```js
var delay = 5000; // delay in milliseconds

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.content').addClass('hide');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.content').removeClass('hide');
    }, delay);
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #19c63c;
  border: 1px solid #169630;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.hide {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Start</button>
<div class="content">content to display...</div>
```

If you want to solve this with only CSS. You can use something like the below. See also [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzxq05ry/10). Note: the animation starts right away.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide-up-wait-down-animation {
  animation: pulse 6000ms;
}


@keyframes pulse {
  0% { height: 200px }
  10% { height: 0; opacity: 0; }  
  90% { height: 0; opacity: 0 }
  100% { height: 200px }
}
```

```html
<div class="content slide-up-wait-down-animation">content to display...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy, event it is a valid solution i need to use only Scss !! Thank you

Comment: I've added a second example which uses CSS to handle the animation. Use those styles in your SCSS stylesheet. Let me know if that answered the question correctly or if there's anything else missing.

Comment: Thanks Roy, but i cant use Jquery, only css :), i cant use $('.content').addClass('hide'); , thanks anyway !

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry for not being specific enough. I now see CSS Animation in the title. It was not clear no JavaScript or jQuery could be used. Have a look at the last example in the answer or jsFiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the support Roy !!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out, no worries! If this answers your question don't forget to update the answer as the accepted one so anyone knows we got to a solution for this.